# What is the probability that the first defective item occurs in the the fifth item inspected

Tags: probability-distribution

Q In a production line, the probability of finding a defective item is 0.3 . What is the probability that the first defective item occurs in the the fifth item inspected.

f(x)=(1−p)^(x−1)P

How to apply this formula here?

Answer (score -1):

Congratulations, you got the right formula for the problem in the first place. This is the hardest part most of the time. Now, let's use it.

[Side note: I don't know why you wrote the "p" uppercase one time and lowercase another time. It should be the same.]

[Side note 2: I assume you know how to evaluate this formula with an electronic calculator. Just to make sure: The notation x^y means "take x to the y-th power", or: "multiply x with itself y times".]

So your formula has two variables (p and x) and you got two numbers (0.3 and 5). What is left is to figure out which is which. I'd say 50% chance to get it right by guessing. Let's increase this chance by understanding the formula.

f(x) is the overall probability that an event with probability (1-p) occurs (x-1) times in a row, followed by one event with probability p.

In your example, we want to find the overall probability that the event "item is ok" occurs 4 times in a row, followed by one event of type "item is defective".

See the correspondences?

Comment: I wonder why this answer was deemed not useful. I tried to answer the original question "how to apply this formula" with as many hints I could possibly give. Obviously, I cannot give a copy-pasteable solution to a homework question. However, I will add some further explanation in case it's not clear how to evaluate this formula.